# R lm(log(y)~x,data) models and predict, need to remember the exp. R2 differences

Tags: r, forecast

I noticed a difference between R and Excel when it comes to trend lines.  Basically I am automating a simple process that someone does.  He/she takes web traffic and finds the best trend line by looking at the R squared to predict what the web traffic will be a few months from now to make sure we will have the servers to handle it.

In R, one can do: lm(log(y)~x,data) but you must "remember" to do **exp**(predict(...)).  Is there a better predict function that remembers the left hand operations?

Also the R-squared reported for log(y)~x is the r squared for x vs that y's log.  The R-squared against the original y was better.  Is there a nifty function that calculates that?

As you can see from this output, what summary reports as the rsquared is not "correct" while my rsq data accurately shows the best rmse. (See source code below.)

```
[1] "rmse is 305221.416535481 rsq is 0.749525713697497 summary$r.squared 0.705953722113025"
[1] "rmse is 304961.752311906 rsq is 0.749815047530537 summary$r.squared 0.706163612870978"
[1] "rmse is 318083.254498832 rsq is 0.723564406971294 summary$r.squared 0.723564406971402"
[1] "rmse is 317352.614485029 rsq is 0.724832898371528 summary$r.squared 0.724832898371531"
```

I want to learn the best way to do this in R...

```
rmse=function(x,y){
  return( sqrt(sum((x-y)^2)/length(x)));
}
rsq=function(actual,pred){    
  return( cor(actual,pred,method=c("pearson"))^2);
}


findBestFormula=function(data,yvar,xvar){
  #This figures out the best Excel-like trend function based on lowest rmse
  data$y=data[,yvar];
  data$x=data[,xvar];  
  models=list(lm(log(y)~log(x),data),
              lm(log(y)~x,data),
             lm(y~log(x),data),
              lm(y~x,data));
  preds=list(exp(predict(models[[1]],data)),
    exp(predict(models[[2]],data)),
    (predict(models[[3]],data)),
    (predict(models[[4]],data)));
  rs=c();
  for(i in (1:4)){
    #say(names(models[[i]]))
    rs[i]=rmse(data$y,preds[[i]]);
    print(paste("rmse is",rs[i],"rsq is",rsq(data$y,preds[[i]]),
                "summary$r.squared",summary(models[[i]])$r.squared));
  }
  best=min(rs)
  #say(best);
  for(i in (1:4)){
    if(best==rs[i]){
      return(list(model=models[[i]],pred=preds[[i]],modelNum=i,rmse=best));  
    }
  }

}


summary(findBestFormula(weekDayDf,'daily','d')$model)
```

Any tips on niftier code to write the above?